# Рассылка сообщений

Tags: c#, очередь

Требуется рассылка сообщений с сервера клиентам.
В среднем 300 раз в секунду, но в пике до 25000 (на несколько секунд).
Размер сообщения около 100 байт.
Клиентов около 200.

Какие технологии можно для этого использовать и какое примерное железо для этого необходимо?

Comment: Что представляет из себя клиент? По какому протоколу клиент общается с сервером? Клиент как то авторизуется на сервере, или нет?

Comment: Да, авторизация должна быть. Протокол в процессе выбора.
Смотрю в сторону WCF

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону [WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/hh975342.aspx) и [SignalR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn802609.aspx)

По железу сказать сложно, но отправка сообщений в 100 байт не должно стоить значительных ресурсов. Ресурсы скорее всего потребляться будут другими частями приложения, которое генерит 25К сообщений

#### Дополнение:

Первое что заставило меня задуматься - это количество отправляемой информации:

у нас есть 200 клиентов, 25К сообщений в секунду, сообщение длинной 100 байт. Из этого мы получаем, что соединение должно успевать обрабатывать 200 * 25000 * 100 / (1024 * 2) = **476,84 МБ трафика** (2,38 МБ на клиента).

Так как у меня в распоряжении старенький ноут с 2х ядерным процом особо выяснить ничего не удалось, остановился я на самом простом уровне - последовательная отдача в асинхронном режиме. Максимально число которое удалось получить *100 сообщений* для *200 клиентов* уходили со скоростью *100 сообщений/сек*, а при *1000 сообщений* - *22 сообщения/сек*. Проблема в том, что при большом количестве сообщений образуется много накладных расходов из-за которых процессор улетает в 100%, т.к. клиенты находились в браузере.

Если интересно [тут пример который я начал делать](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1IIWW-zwZYyUUVjSjFRZkU3UWM)

Comment: Эти 25к сообщений также приходят через сокет. Т.е. по сути нужен ретранслятор.

Comment: @jshapen, зачем ещё прослойку городить? Если сервер не будет справляться, можно подключать очереди и т.п.

Comment: Потому что отправлять данные нужно всем 200 клиентам а получают данные только на сервере

Comment: @jshapen, опишите подробнее свою ситуацию и что вы хотите, технологии я предложил, а как ими пользоваться это вы уже подумаете, если не знаете как отослать сообщение 200 клиентам на сокеты - задайте вопрос и вам на него ответят

Comment: Как отослать 200 клиентам на сокет знаю, а вот как сделать правильно 25000 раз в секунду это другое дело.

Comment: @jshapen, ну тут смотреть надо, 25к на 200 - это 5М итераций, если в один поток последовательно отдавать не удаётся - попробуйте разбить на большее количество потоков, [пример посмотрите тут](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml). Найду время - попробую сделать что-то вроде бенчмарка, самому стало интересно

Comment: @jshapen, я обновил ответ, может из того, что я сделал вам хоть что-то да поможет